# Why hibernate generates 'T_' prefix tableName during insert and delete operation?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

**Database: ORACLE**

We are using ImprovedNamingStrategy for hibernate and in hbm file, we are giving table name explicitly.

But, still, during delete and insert operations, it is generating 'T_' as prefix and 'HT_' as prefix against some tables.

This is resulting in SQLGrammarException:

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Please note that this is happening while using Oracle database, it is not happening with HSQL or Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're running some bulk-operations and this are temporary tables. Here is a [topic](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043080) at the official Hibernate forum with most likely the same problem.  And here is an [article](http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/), explaining, why this tables are needed.

And the workaround is to avoid bulk-operations or just let Hibernate create this temporary tables.

Comment: will this occur only in Oracle?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity don't think so, because it's rather ORM-specific, then database specific. May be you have some restrictions with Oracle to create this temp tables, but they are created in HSQL and PD databases?

Comment: how to avoid temporary table creation? is there any flag or configuration, so that we can set and avoid?